# como restaurar una VM desde imagen de disco qcow2

Tags: linux, vps, virtualización

tuve un problema con mi servidor y mi proveedor de VPS solo me quiso dar un respaldo del disco de la VM en formato qcow2 me dijo que debia virtualizar y montar eso y alli sacar mi data y desresposabilizo , ahora me encuentro que no se como puedo explorar mis archivos en dicha imagen de disco tenia en la vm WHM y capnel necesito recuperar esos archivos.

Podria usar virtualbox en widnows o debo monatar todo en un Servidor linux, tengo VPS linux o mi maquina personal que es widnows, como podria yo sacar la data de un cpanel que tenia alli ?

necsito ayuda please

Comment: Si es un cPanel lo vas a tener complicado si quieres usar tu máquina personal, porque cPanel solo permite ejecutarse en IPs públicas. Aún así deberías poder acceder al disco y sacar datos por ahí, pero dudo que ni te arranque como cPanel propiamente dicho. El formato qcow2 es del software de virtualización QEMU, por lo tanto necesitas una máquina que pueda instalarlo y correr esa imagen. Una vez lo consigas podrás acceder a su disco y buscar lo que necesites. Siendo cPanel, si tenias las copias de seguridad activadas, lo mejor será que las busques en /backups/ para recuperar las BD tambien.

Comment: Aunque lo más sencillo es que todo eso lo haga tu proveedor de VPS en un VPS nuevo y con IP pública, pues ellos conocen la mejor forma de hacerlo, y si te da algun problema de licencia de cPanel pagas una por un mes y tienes ese tiempo para recuperar bien los datos (eso si no te dejan un plazo de prueba gratis por ser una nueva IP pública).

Comment: MI proveedor no me va ayudar a montar eso en otro VPS y de hacerlo tengo uq eyo darle el VPS que se lo di pero que eso no es trabajo de ellos porque los backup no se hicieor por un bug de whm que no es culpa de ellos y si me ayudan es cuando puidan en dias etc y tengo sitio off, asi que debe solucionar yo tengo un VPS donde podria hacer todo no me importa que no arranqueo conseguir 1 mes de whm lo puedo hacer quiero es sacar la data de 1 cpanel mas nada, como puedo arrancar esa VM en otro VPS conoces algun guide ?

Comment: A ver, QEMU es un emulador de máquinas virtuales, por lo tanto seguramente no puedes ejecutarlo dento de un VPS, porque ya son maquinas virtuales de por si, sino que más bien tienes que hacerlo dentro de un servidor dedicado.  Es decir, no creo que se pueda montar una máquina virtual (VPS) dentro de otra máquina virtual (VPS) y esperar que salga bien.

Comment: Si estás dispuesto a pagar por eso quizás deberías postear el curro en Upwork y buscar profesionales allí que sepan hacerlo (ojo con eso, pues alli recibirás muchas ofertas de gente que no tiene ni idea, pero revisa bien sus perfiles y sabrás el grado de responsabilidad y éxito que tienen y si te puedes fiar).  Si intentas hacerlo tu y nunca lo has hecho antes te va a costar tiempo y más de una fustración seguramente.

Comment: Yo tengo servidor dedicadod de hetzner pero no se como proceder , e usado esos dedcicaos con promox hace tiempo pero no e usaod quemo y tampoco restaurado una vm con un archivo de imagen de quemu.

Comment: Por eso te digo que te busques un profesional.  En este sitio no van a ayudarte con esto porque es para programación, no para gestion de VPS o servidores dedicados. Si quieres puedes probar en [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) (en inglés) que se dedican más a ese tipo de preguntas. Suerte!